# R : Error in " " : incorrect number of dimensions , when using intersect

Tags: r, dataframe, intersection

So I am basically trying calculate diffrences between datasets, but for some reason I receive the following error:`"Error in expr1[overlap, ]: incorrect number of dimensions` It might be very simple but I can't seem to fix it.

I am reading 4 .RData files.They all contain the dataframe `Expr` which has around 54000 rows and 10 columns with data. All files have the same column names but the rows names are not the same but for a big part they are so by using intersect I calculate the overlap but somehow this doesn't work as it should.

Example of the files:

```
file1:
               GSM10     GSM11
    1007_s_at  7.777639  8.582393
    1053_at    9.029875  7.937305
    117_at     7.026750  6.271279
    121_at     7.800896  7.842556
    1255_g_at  3.472406  3.486788
    1294_at    6.332505  6.176560

file2:
               GSM10     GSM11
    1007_s_at  8.471424  9.499584
    1053_at    9.047367  7.981026
    1255_g_at  4.231098  4.226397
    1294_at    7.482370  7.289183
```

Thanks in advance!!

Part of the code:

```
data <- list()
load("file1")  
data$old_fRMA <- expr
load("file2") 
data$old_PMfRMA <- expr   
#runTimeInfo
load("file3") 
data$new_PMfRMA <- expr   
load("file3") 
data$new_fRMA <- expr

##
compare.fRMA <-
  function(expr1, expr2, no_duplicate_probeset = no_duplicate_probeset) {
    overlap <- intersect(rownames(expr1), rownames(expr2))
    expr1 <- expr1[overlap,]
    expr2 <- expr2[overlap,]

    datalength <- length(colnames(expr1))
    difference <-
      sapply(1:datalength, function(x)
        abs(expr1[x] - expr2[x]))
    difference.max <- sapply(difference, max)
    difference.mean <- sapply(difference, mean)

    out <- list()
    #### All probesets ####
    out$maxall <- max(difference.max)
    out$meanall <- mean(difference.mean)

    #################
    expr1 <- expr1[no_duplicate_probeset,]
    expr2 <- expr2[no_duplicate_probeset,]

    difference <-
      sapply(1:datalength, function(x)
        abs(expr1[x] - expr2[x]))
    difference.max <- sapply(difference, max)
    difference.mean <- sapply(difference, mean)

    #### TG probesets ####
    out$maxTG <- max(difference.max)
    out$meanTG <- mean(difference.mean)
    return(out)
  }

res <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  res[i] <- list()
  for (j in (i + 1):4) {
    if (j>4) { break()

    }
    # print(paste(i,j ,sep=","))
    res[i][j] <- compare.fRMA(data[i], data[j])

  }
}
```

Comment: use `debug(compare.fRMA)`

Comment: Sorry for that, I did put an example of the data.

Comment: You only gave a printed form of your data - from that it is not easy to reproduce your data. Please read [how to give the data in a reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).